# Using bootstrap in web components shadowDOM

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, web-component, shadow-dom, lit-element

What's the easiest way to use a large css library (like bootstrap) in web components / shadowDOM app using LitElement?
Tried the following:

1. Use the link tag within the component.  Works, but creates FOUC (flash of unstyled content).
2. Render everything to Light DOM (I'm using LitElement and they have a createRenderRoot() override. Works as well, but as the app gets more complex, maintaining component document isolation would be nice.

Looking for the simplest way to just use boostrap in this setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LitElement's recommended way to add styles to components is via the [`styles`](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/styles#add-styles) property. Loading external `.css` files this way is not straightforward, but there are some solutions.

**The `import` way**

If your definition of "simplest way" comprises using transpilers or module bundlers then you can use non-js inlined imports to accomplish something like the following:

```js
import bootstrap from './path/to/bootstrap.css';
// ...

class MyElement extends LitElement {

  static styles = bootstrap; // If your build system already converted
                             // the stylesheet to a CSSResult

  static styles = unsafeCss(bootstrap); // If bootstrap is plain text

}
```

There are many plugins dedicated to this: see for example [babel-plugin-inline-import](https://github.com/feats/babel-plugin-inline-import), [rollup-plugin-lit-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-lit-css),  [rollup-plugin-postcss-lit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-postcss-lit), [webpack-lit-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lit-css-loader).

**The wrapper way**

If you want to keep things (almost) buildless you can write a simple `postinstall` script that generates a `.js` file that exports the lit-ified styles:

```js
// bootstrap.css.js
import {css} from 'lit-element';

export const bootstrap = css`
<bootstrap here>
`;

// my-element.js
import {bootstrap} from './bootstrap.css.js';

class MyElement extends LitElement {
  static styles = bootstrap;
}
```

**About Shadow DOM**

If you want to use Shadow DOM you'll have to import the library in *every* component that needs to use it, even nested ones. This is not as onerous as it seems thanks to [Constructable Stylesheets](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/constructable-stylesheets), used by Lit under the hood; think of it as a way for components to join style contexts more than a replication of identical stylesheets. Also, to keep things organized you can create a "base" component that imports bootstrap and extend it wherever needed:

```js
import bootstrap from 'path/to/bootstrap.css';

export class BaseElement extends LitElement {
  static styles = bootstrap;
}

class MyElement extends BaseElement {
  render() {
    // Bootstrap is ready to use here!
    return html``;
  }
}
```

---

Lit documentation about style sharing: https://lit.dev/docs/components/styles/#sharing-styles

Comment: awesome - thank you!  I'm already using webpack and also have a base class, anyway so the base class + bundler looks like a good way to go.  Will try some bundlers and go from there.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Awesome! It seems like there is one drawback -- if your whole site isn't built in webcomponents then either method is going to involve twice loading the css files -- once in your site html's style tag, and once in the webpack content.  Nonetheless, way better than the "Flash of Unstyled Content" problem.

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert you're right. You could reuse the same constructed stylesheet of your components and apply it to `document` though, see [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/constructable-stylesheets#using_constructed_stylesheets).

Comment: while this worked great for bootstrap, it didn't work as well for my site's custom css which imported a webfont since `@import` isn't available in CSSResult.  But it's given a lot of good directions to go in.

Comment: @Umbo's suggestion for applying to document is the way of the future, but at present adoptedStyleSheets is still not available on Firefox or Safari.  :-(